# How NOT filter LINQ results if criteria list is empty?

Tags: vb.net, linq, linq-to-sql, contains

When filter criteria is passed to my LINQ query, no problem:

```
Dim statesSelected As String = {‘GA’,’FL’}

Dim results As IEnumerable(Of Person) = _
From p As Person in dc.Persons _
Where statesSelected.Contains(p.StateCode)
```

HOWEVER, if no filter criteria are selected, then I want ALL states returned (instead of none which is what the above would do).  How can I do this, please?  I realize I could have an IF statement around the query, but in reality I’ll have many filters (and will want to handle them all within the one query).

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Try if else approach!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this would translate to SQL, but you can try this approach:

```
Dim results As IEnumerable(Of Person) = _
From p As Person in dc.Persons _
Where statesSelected Is Nothing OrElse statesSelected.Contains(p.StateCode)
```

In this case if your variable `statesSelected` is nothing then only the first part of query would be executed, otherwise first part would be true and only second condition would matter

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
Dim results As IEnumerable(Of Person) = _
From p As Person In Persons
Where If(statesSelected.Length < 1, p.StateCode <> "", statesSelected.Contains(p.StateCode))
```

What it's doing is checking to make sure statesSelected has elements. If not, it simply brings back all elements. If there values in statesSelected, it brings back the ones that contain that state.

The magic is happening in the ternary If() : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513985.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396